# How to change the location of Spring STS tool repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am getting the following error when run spring boot application.

Actually `.m2` repository accidentally deleted. When re-running the application it is updated, but it is showing the following error. please do help in this regard.

Archive for required library:

> C:/Users/Sathish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.6/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar'
>   in project 'Application' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the mentioned JAR file in the local Maven repository is corrupt. I would delete this file manually from the repository, go back to STS, and run an "Maven -> Update Project...", maybe also checking the "Force Download of Snapshots/Releases". That should help.